# "A last couple of week" vs. "the last couple of weeks"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What is the difference in meaning between *a last couple of weeks* and *the last couple of weeks*? I thought that the former was totally wrong, but in the second episode of the fourth season of *Breaking Bad*, Walt uses exactly that. Here is the context:

> Walt: I feel like I need to explain myself. There were some actions that I took which I want you to understand. I
> didn't want any of this to happen. Everything I did, I did out of
> loyalty to my partner. And then, later... ...of course... ...purely
> out of self-defense. I hope you can appreciate that. Just like I
> appreciated that... I appreciate that when you were going to kill
> me... ...you were simply following orders. I get that. Completely. And
> I harbor no ill will.
>
> Mike: Well, there's a load off my mind.

> Walt: Mike, I'm trying to tell you... Mike: I get it. Fine.
>
> Mike:Drink up, Walter.
>
> Walt: Hell of **a last couple of weeks**.
>
> Makes a man wonder exactly where he stands.

How would the meaning would change if he use *the* insdead of *a* there?

Comment: `Hell of a` is a fixed phrase. Hell of a last 2 weeks. Hell of a last month. Hell of a last period of time.

Comment: "Hell of a last couple of weeks" is colloquial, The full version is "This has been a Hell of a last couple of weeks." "Last couple of weeks" is understood as one unit of time..**Hell of *a*** = **Hell of *an example of*** (Hell = a very bad experience) Compare "He was a giant of a man"

Comment: Thank for the helpful comments! I guess that would make a reasonable answer